# Show inputted data into another html

Tags: php, html

I'm new to html and I want my inputted data to show into another form..

I want to show the First Name and Last Name in a different html or php by using a button..

[image]

```
<tr>
<td>First Name: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="fn"></td>
</tr>

<td>Last Name: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="ln"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you installed apache?

Comment: you need to setup a server,, try looking for wamp or xampp for windows,, and lamp, mamp for linux or mac respectively.

Comment: If you are doing this in PHP post the data from your current form and access it in other page using `$_POST["name"]`

Comment: What different HTML? Where? On the same page or another page?

Comment: I don't use apache but I'm currently using xampp..

Comment: I want to show the value in another page..

Comment: use $_POST['fn'] & $_POST['ln'] in your php file

Answer (score 1):

Try it. In your html, you will do:

```
<form action="data.php" method="post">
<tr>
<td>First Name: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="fn"></td>
</tr>

<td>Last Name: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="ln"></td>
</tr>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Then create a file called data.php

**data.php**

```
<?php

echo "First Name: " $_POST['fn'];
echo "Last Name: " $_POST['ln'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok Let's suppose you have your current page login.php

**login.php**

```
<form action="show.php" method="post">
<tr>
<td>First Name: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="fn"></td>
</tr>

<td>Last Name: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="ln"></td>
</tr> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and another page called show.php on which you are showing the data:

**show.php**

```
<?php
  $fn = $_POST["fn"];
  $ln = $_POST["ln"];

  echo "First Name: ".$fn."\n"."Last Name: ".$ln;
?>
```

You need to run these files on your xampp server and give correct path for each file.

I hope this is very simple example.